# Leitura remota no Android: Json ou XML?

Tags: android, json, xml

Estou iniciando no Android e também não tenho muita experiencia em Java. Minha primeira aplicação terá uma consulta a um servidor remoto.
Minha duvida é a seguinte:

No Android (consequentemente no Java) o que é mais prático, na hora de se obter os dados: em Json ou em XML?

Answer (score 4):

Resumidamente JSON é bastante conciso e de fácil interpretação pela máquina. Já  XML é mais expressivo, você consegue expressar dialetos complexos, contudo é bastante verboso em relação a JSON, assim a representação de um mesmo conjunto de dados tende a ser significativamente maior.

Especificamente para Java/Android existem ótima bibliotecas de manipulação para ambos os formatos, porém se você não sabe o que usar eu recomendaria ir com JSON pois é o formato mais simples.

Answer (score 2):

Concordo com o BrunoBR, XML é mais verboso e com maior possibilidades de dialetos do que o JSON, que por sua vez é mais simples e mais fácil de entender.

Quanto a praticidade, existem frameworks muito bons para se lidar com os dois, então, não vejo isso como um critério que influencie fortemente na decisão de escolha entre um ou outro. Eu levaria mais em consideração a velocidade de conversão de XML-> Java e Java->XML em relação a velocidade de conversão de JSON->Java e Java->JSON e o tamanho do arquivo que será transferido do web service para a aplicação. Em um dispositivo móvel com hardware limitado e internet limitada, qualquer detalhe na performance faz diferença.

Tem um [post](http://tuhrig.de/jaxb-vs-gson-and-jackson/) muito bom do Thomas Uhrig comparando performance dos frameworks Java que lidam com JSON x frameworks Java que lidam com XML. Como resultado dos testes realizados por ele, chegou-se as seguintes conclusões:

> O primeiro resultado dos meus testes foi que o framework Jackson
>   (JSON) escreve os dados um pouco mais rápido do que o framework
>   JAXB(XML) e o framework Gson(JSON). A diferença não é muita.

A escrita Java->XML e Java->JSON não teve muita diferença de performance entre os 3, mas disse que o Jackson realizou a tarefa um pouco mais rápido que os outros 2.

> O mais interessante é o fato de que as duas implementações de
>   frameworks para JSON (Jackson e Gson) lêem data muito mais rápido do
>   que do que o JAXB.

Ele percebeu que a leitura de JSON -> Java nos dois frameworks foi muito mais rápida do que de XML -> Java no framework JAXB.

> O arquivo JSON foi cerca de 68% do tamanho do arquivo XML
>   correspondente.

Se colocarmos o mesmo conteudo em um arquivo XML e em um arquivo JSON, o arquivo JSON será 68% mais leve. Agora, pense como isso pode fazer total diferença se levarmos em consideração a internet móvel que temos no nosso país.
Precisamos levar muito em consideração o tamanho do que será transferido do web service para aplicação, isso é conceito básico. Demora para o carregamento de um conjunto de dados pode fazer o usuário vivenciar uma péssima experiência. Usuário não gosta de esperar, tiro isso por mim =D.

Comment: Esqueci de comentar, meus web services são RESTful, retorno sempre JSON e nas minhas aplicações eu uso o framework Gson para lidar com o JSON recebido. Gson é um framework MUUUITO simples de se lidar. Abração!

Comment: Otima explicação dos dois, também retorno sempre JSON dos meus WebServices pois acho ele muito mais fácil de entender e escrever.